# Bash command based file manager

Tags: command-line, bash, ls

Is there a way I could run 'ls' command, and be able to navigate through the results using the arrow keys, and selecting with spacebar, possibly going back by pushing escape?

Is it something that can be done using only bash commands?

I'm trying to create a simple bash command based operating system, so I guess this would be selectable from a menu

Comment: Why does it have to be "Bash-based" - what's your rationale? There are many good CLI file managers, like Midnight Commander and Ranger, but those are either made in C or Python. Bash scripting is not designed to do everything - it's a shell with scripting capabilities.

Comment: Advice to newcomers: If an answer solves your problem, please accept it by clicking the large check mark (✓) next to it and optionally also up-vote it (up-voting requires at least 15 reputation points). If you found other answers helpful, please up-vote them. Accepting and up-voting helps future readers.

Comment: @824NZ We are happy that you finally decided to join us … This community is powered by volunteers like you so the more the merrier :-) … Questions here, however, are expected to be focused and concise with context directly targeted at explaining the question … Therefore, I think if you remove the very last paragraph, that would make **a perfect** question … Welcome again to AskUbuntu

Answer (score 2):

You can try `mc` aka [*Midnight Commander*](https://www.midnight-commander.org):

```
$ LANG=C apt-cache show mc
Package: mc
Section: universe/utils
Origin: Ubuntu
[...]

Homepage: https://www.midnight-commander.org
Description-en: Midnight Commander - a powerful file manager
 GNU Midnight Commander is a text-mode full-screen file manager. It
 uses a two panel interface and a subshell for command execution. It
 includes an internal editor with syntax highlighting and an internal
 viewer with support for binary files. Also included is Virtual
 Filesystem (VFS), that allows files on remote systems (e.g. FTP, SSH
 servers) and files inside archives to be manipulated like real files.
```

[image: mc]

Comment: 1st emotion that comes up: nostalgia

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way I could run 'ls' command, and be able to navigate
> through the results using the arrow keys, and selecting with spacebar,
> possibly going back by pushing escape?
>
> Is it something that can be done using only bash commands?

Sure, **[fff (Fucking Fast File-Manager)](https://github.com/dylanaraps/fff)** is what you need to look into ... It's not just a working console file-manager written entirely in `bash` but it is also a great learning resource as the author(*thankfully*) provides an extensively commented [source code](https://github.com/dylanaraps/fff/blob/master/fff) ... The main source file `fff` itself is a bash script that cab be simply run by e.g.:

```bash
bash fff
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try [`ncdu`](http://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu/).

It's purpose is to browse files/dirs, show where dirs takes the most space, then you can delete files or other options, like open a `shell`.

You can change the way files are sorted. By size, alphabetically...

[image: ncdu]